# How to replace existing subversion repo with unversioned unbranched copy using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

A vendor grabbed an exported copy of a repository and made large scale changes that include adding and deleting folders. Since this was an export, there was no change tracking. We want to completely replace the current trunk with this heavily modified version without losing version history.

I had hoped to import the new version and use svn switch, but svn complained that it was an unrelated copy.

Answer (score 2):

Treat it as a [vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

1. Create a branch from trunk
2. Check out the branch
3. Run svn_load_dirs.pl to get caught up
4. Commit the branch
5. Merge the branch back to trunk

Comment: Not familiar with that. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you now have 2 repositories that you want to 'merge' by taking your original one, and then putting the new ones revisions into it.

If so, i think you need to simply svndump the new repo, and then svnload it into the old one. You must use the svnadmin tools that operate on the repos, rather than the working copy, if you want to keep the history contained within the new repo.